# Add a function to a route?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Here's my route:

```
Route::get('log-in', array(
'as' => 'log-in',
'uses' => 'AuthController@getLogIn'
));
```

What's the best way to add in a test to it:

```
Route::get('log-in', function()
{
    if (Auth::check())//do something
});
```

I know i could add it as a filter but I only need it on this route.

Comment: Why not do it as a filter anyway? `Route::get('log-in', array('before' => 'filtername', 'as' => 'log-in', 'uses' => 'AuthController@getLogIn'));`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do both, have a function and a controller action in your route, so I see three options:

1) Add it as s filter, which is the best one.

2) Instantiate your controller inside that closure (anonymous function) and call the action from it.

3) Do the `Auth::check()` inside your controller or any service class called by your controller.

Answer (score 0):

The auth filte already exists, why not use it?

```
Route::get('log-in', array(
'before' => 'auth',
'as' => 'log-in',
'uses' => 'AuthController@getLogIn'
));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a filter in the 'app/filter.php' file like this:

```
Route::filter('myFilterName', function() {

    if (!Auth::check())
    {
            return Redirect::route('MyNamedRoutToLoginPage');
    }
});
```

Then you could use it in 'app/routes.php' file like this:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'myFilterName'), function() {

// do your action here if user is logged

});
```